# How can I create nice graphs from the internals of Maven runs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I would like to create some statistics for my `Selenium UI-Test` Job in Jenkins. Calculating the metrics in the maven Job is easy but is there any way to add a graph to the Jenkins Jobs with the numbers I generate?

For example I calculate the average site response time in my UI-Tests and add it with other metrics as an output artifact (e.g. a JSON document). How can I show a graph that displays those metrics over the previous x runs directly inside Jenkins?

I'm not entirely sure this is the correct stack exchange site so point me in the right direction if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not some default JUnit reporter (or some other popular reporters), then you can create your own html page and publish using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin